# Does Remotelock through the Graph API work?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to make remoteLock work however I'm always getting the following error:

{
"error": {
"code": "BadRequest",
"message": "{\r\n  "_version": 3,\r\n  "Message": "An error has occurred - Operation ID (for customer support): 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 - Activity ID: db4dc989-7ba7-4bf1-8498-62ef8c5defb5 - Url: [https://fef.amsub0202.manage.microsoft.com/DeviceFE/StatelessDeviceFEService/deviceManagement/managedDevices('e85b9c69-fd4c-405c-bc34-2af1dc84f645')/microsoft.management.services.api.remoteLock?api-version=2022-07-29\",\r\n](https://fef.amsub0202.manage.microsoft.com/DeviceFE/StatelessDeviceFEService/deviceManagement/managedDevices(%27e85b9c69-fd4c-405c-bc34-2af1dc84f645%27)/microsoft.management.services.api.remoteLock?api-version=2022-07-29%5C%22,%5Cr%5Cn)  "CustomApiErrorPhrase": "",\r\n  "RetryAfter": null,\r\n  "ErrorSourceService": "",\r\n  "HttpHeaders": "{}"\r\n}",
"innerError": {
"date": "2023-04-25T12:41:30",
"request-id": "db4dc989-7ba7-4bf1-8498-62ef8c5defb5",
"client-request-id": "db4dc989-7ba7-4bf1-8498-62ef8c5defb5"
}
}
}

Am I doing something wrong?

Doing a GET on /deviceManagement/managedDevices/{managedDeviceId} gives me my device details. However the RemoteLock with a POST doesn't seem to work.

Following the documentation link below, I've set Accpet and Authorization headers corerectly and the body of the request is empty.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-devices-manageddevice-remotelock?view=graph-rest-1.0

Answer (score 1):

I have the answer to this now.

RemoteLock is supported on Android but not on Windows.